# How to compile specific .ts file and write into dist folder (.js format)

Tags: angular

i am using angular 4 and angular-cli.json (version - 1.6.8). I have requirement to compile specific .ts file and write into dist folder.

Can you please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: if you create a new angular-cli app , by default typescript configuration will be there , please make sure that you have installed typescipt compiler npm install typescript --save-dev

Comment: tsc -out output.js filea.ts fileb.ts... <- output to single file output.js